# Token generation in REST API WCS

Tags: api, rest, websphere-commerce, wcs

How the WCToken can be generated without 
invoking either the login/guest services in REST API?

We can use the WCToken generated form either login/guest and calling various other webservices to retrieve data, how can we call other services without calling login/guest?

I have found from my observation like, WCToken is generated based on the userId along with 2 more tokens(activitytokenid, activitytokenSignature).
Is this WCToken stored in any database tables?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  The WCToken is for maintaining a session, so how would you create a session if you aren't going to identify the user as a guest or registered user?  What is the use case?

Answer (score 1):

> How the WCToken can be generated without invoking either the login/guest services in REST API?

This isn't possible without customization.

> We can use the WCToken generated form either login/guest and calling various other webservices to retrieve data, how can we call other services without calling login/guest?

You can call REST services without calling login or guest first. Your request will be handled as a generic user.

> I have found from my observation like, WCToken is generated based on the userId along with 2 more tokens(activitytokenid, activitytokenSignature). Is this WCToken stored in any database tables?

The data within the token is an encrypted version of what is stored in the CTXMGT table.